# How to load several images from the same folder?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, glob

I would like to load several images from the same folder. The code below is however yielding an error:

```
(TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a30c12347c11> in <module>
2 import glob
3 
----> 4 image_list = map(Image.open, glob('/Users/name/images/*.jpg'))
5 
6 object_detection_api(image_list, rect_th=2, text_th=1, text_size=1)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)
```

I have already checked some trouble-shooting pages but the given notification keeps appearing. What do I have to amend in the code?

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

image_list = map(Image.open, glob('/Users/name/images/*.jpg'))

object_detection_api(image_list, rect_th=2, text_th=1, text_size=1)
```

As requested, I am pasting below the code for the object_detection_api as well:

```
def object_detection_api(img_path, threshold=0.7, rect_th=3, text_size=3, text_th=3):
  """
  object_detection_api
    parameters:
      - img_path - path of the input image
      - threshold - threshold value for prediction score
      - rect_th - thickness of bounding box
      - text_size - size of the class label text
      - text_th - thichness of the text
    method:
      - prediction is obtained from get_prediction method
      - for each prediction, bounding box is drawn and text is written
        with opencv
      - the final image is displayed
  """
  boxes, pred_cls = get_prediction(img_path, threshold)
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  for i in range(len(boxes)):
    cv2.rectangle(img, boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1],color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=rect_th)
    cv2.putText(img,pred_cls[i], boxes[i][0], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, text_size, (0,255,0),thickness=text_th)
  plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Post the full exception and the code for `object_detection_api()`

Comment: It _looks_ like `object_detection_api()` function is expecting its first argument to be a file-like object not a list. It's impossible to say for sure or tell you how to fix it because you haven't included enough code and error information in your question.

Comment: Have added further details - I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps. `object_detection_api()` is expecting its first argument to be path (which are usually strings) to an image file. You're passing it a generator that yields a series of PIL image objects.

Comment: Yes I had thought about that too... when using a single jpg file name for image_list (as opposed to a folder), it is recognizing the image file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```py
import os
ls = [x for x in os.listdir('/Users/name/images/') if x.endswith('.jpg')]
im_list = ['/Users/name/images/'+x for x in ls]
for img_path in im_list:
   object_detection_api(img_path)
```

May work for you.

Keep in mind that `map()` and `filter` make generators, and if you need to eagerly evaluate them, you can call `list()` on them to put them in a list.

Credit to @Gwang-JinKim for all the help!

Comment: Good idea but it results in the following message "TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments."

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the second argument and `/` in making `im_list`, try the updated answer?

Comment: No worries - the updated version is resulting in 2 errors though: AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'seek' / AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Thanks, it is yielding the same two error notifications unfortunately...

Comment: Hmmm, what about `image_list = list(map(lambda x: Image.open(x), im_list))`

Comment: more pythonic than `map(fun, lst)` is: `[func(x) for x in lst]` - so use list expressions instead of `list(map())`.  so @robotHamster's suggestion would be:`image_list = [Image.open(x) for x in im_list]`

Comment: The change to ```image_list = list(map(lambda x: Image.open(x), im_list))``` yielded the same two errors... good idea with the change to func - this one is only leaving one error for now ```NameError: name 'func' is not defined```

Comment: I would try the one I just updated to. @Gwang-JinKim used `func` to be generic and illustrate that you can use an arbitrary function. Thanks @Gwang-JunKim for bringing up comprehensions!

Comment: @robotHamster: welcome! :) - I am a fan of list expressions, because if you change the `[ ]` around them to `( )` they become generators. And they are very clear.

Comment: That's great, the amended code seems to work. One last thing: I get feedback that there is "no such directory", although Python clearly recognised a file in its error message: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/name/images/155566483.jpg'```. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: @robotHamster: `list(filter(predicate_func, lst))` is `[x for x in lst if predicate_func(x)]`.

Comment: That's the python interpreter telling you it cannot find a file when it attempts to access the path specified. Does your machine actually have a user names `name`?

Comment: @M.S.: you forgot the beginning '/' - it is an absolute path and not a relative one. '/Users/name/...' and not 'Users/name/...'

Comment: Thanks @Gwang-JinKim, I am very familiar with them and use them every day, it just slipped my mind...

Comment: That's my personal name, which I am always amending in the script. Have just kept it out of the public postings, that's why...

Comment: @M.S. what I meant: you forgot "/" before "Users".

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim is right, I forgot to iclude `/` in the comprehension

Comment: Adding the / before Users is getting things back to the two errors unfortunately: ```AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'seek' / AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'read'``` So the issue may lie somewhere else

Comment: @M.S. as we said - use list expressions first. then nothing can be wrong with `map` object first.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance here but do you mean the list expressions should be included in ```def object_detection_api``` already to make things consistent?

Comment: Ok let me see how to get there. Regards in any case to Freiburg and Rapid City and thanks for your help

Comment: @M.S. - `object_detection_api()` takes as first argument the image's path. So don't do `image_list = [Image.open(x) for x in im_list]` but do `for img_pth in im_list: object_detection_api(img_path)`. - welcome! :)